# How I can get UIWebViews id in java script?

Tags: javascript, ios, objective-c, uiwebview, local-storage

I use UIWebView in the iOS project.
In js code in this webview I use local storage (reading data from local storage by key and writing data to local storage by key).

```
var items = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('key')) || []; //reading

localStorage.setItem('key', newJson);  // writing
```

Now I use only one key for using local storage.
It works fine.

But local storage in common for all UIWebViews in the project (Am I right or not?). And when I use two or more UIWebView in the project (js code is similar for all webviews), that I need use more than one key for using local storage (one key for every UIWebView) in order to every webview use own storage.

How I can define which UIWebView uses local storage now in order to use key for this UIWebView?
How I can get UIWebViews id in java script?

Answer (score 0):

You can save an object in `localStorage()`.

In this way you can save data for more that one `UIWebView` in client memory and retrieve it easily by key.

An example:

```
 // create an object with some properties (as value use data from UIWebView)
var uIWebViews = { 'uIWebView1': 1, 'uIWebView2': 2, 'uIWebView3': 3 };

// save your object into local storage
localStorage.setItem('uIWebViews', JSON.stringify(uIWebViews));

// retrieve the object from storage, remember to parse it
var retrievedObject = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('uIWebViews'));

// get the object
console.log('retrievedObject: ', uIWebViews);

// get a property, equivalent to get a key
console.log('key uIWebView2 has value: ', uIWebViews.uIWebView2);
```

Live example, please open console to see the result: https://jsfiddle.net/hsf8gf8d/

Comment: thank you for your answer, but how I can know in which UIWebView I is now?  js code is similar for all webviews

Answer (score 0):

To let the JS code know what webview it runs in I would call its `stringByEvaluatingJavaScriptFromString:` method with a predefined JS method that sets a variable in your page. So your JS code could have something like

```
function setWebViewID(webViewID) {
    // save the identifier somewhere and perhaps call other functions              
}
```

Then in the webView, once the page is loaded and all, you call

```
[myWebView stringByEvaluatingJavaScriptFromString:@"setWebViewID(\"myID\")"]
```

The trick is usually ensuring that the content is done with any other stuff it does in JS right after loading. If you need something like that I'd recommend using `WKWebView`, `WKUserContentController` and to look into `addScriptMessageHandler:name:`. With that you can properly set up listening for events in JS from the webview.